# Sitecore User Group - Budapest #1

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**About the event:**

The first Hungarian Sitecore User Group has been announced! There will be two topics:

- Sitecore Azure - Tamás Varga (@Sitecore)
- Item serialization with Unicorn - Tamás Tárnok (@ALLWIN Informatika)

Free discussions, pizza, drink and beer after the presentations.

**When (UTC):** Tuesday, March 28, 2017 5:00 PM

**Where:** ALLWIN Informatika, Bartók Béla út 9., Budapest

**[RSVP to this Event](https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Budapest/events/238076835/)**

Comment: Can we have the times in UTC please

Comment: Thank you! Updated.

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins on Mar 18 at 17:00